# several catkin workspaces

Tags: ros, multiple, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Is it possible to have several catkin workspaces and to source them sequentially in the .bashrc without conflict or may we experience issues with that?

```
source /ws1/devel/setup.bash
source /ws2/devel/setup.bash
source /ws3/devel/setup.bash
# ...
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175234/several-catkin-workspaces/) by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 454 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-06-28**:
Effectively the last line will "overwrite" all previously sources workspaces. You should chain your workspaces on top of each other as described in the answer from @joq and only source the leaf workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For people having packages coming from different git/subversion repositories with their own file hierarchy not catkin-compliant and wanted to create several catkin workspaces because of these, I suggest to create a unique "central" catkin workspaces with symbolic links pointing to your git/svn repos, by this way you don't break the file hierarchy of your repos.

```
courrier@zbook:~/ros_ws/src$ ls -l
total 29
lrwxrwxrwx 1 courrier courrier   42 Sep 16 12:22 baxter_common -> /home/courrier/packages_ros/src/baxter_common/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 courrier courrier   48 Sep  9 19:25 CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
lrwxrwxrwx 1 courrier courrier   47 Sep 10 15:02 lemon_moveit_config -> /home/courrier/inria/asv1/src/lemon_moveit_config/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 courrier courrier   26 Sep 11 13:34 lemon_ros -> /home/courrier/university/lemon_ros/
[...]
```

---

Originally posted by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) with karma: 454 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problems are likely to arise. That approach is not recommended.

What should work reliably is to create

- ws1 as an overlay of /opt/ros/hydro.setup.bash (for example)
- ws2 as an overlay of ws1
- ws3 as an overlay of ws2

Then, `source /ws3/devel/setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-07-03**:
Oops.  This might explain some problems I've been having.  Thanks, ROS Answers!

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-07-23**:
I'm following the tutorial about how to create a proper overlay (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) but I don't get it. What do they do different from me with my 3 "source"?

I don't have this message "This workspace overlays blablabla" so I'm missing something but what?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-07-23**:
I don't think the documentation is very clear about this. What I posted is the recommended solution. Maybe others can explain why.

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-07-23**:
That is what I wanted to do, but how do you create an overlay, then? I found out that tutorial above and... apparently what it does is only sourcing all setup.bash in the right order. Isn’t it what I was doing in my initial post?